# Changing a parameter by specific time in NDSolve in a COVID-19 spread simulation

Tags: differential-equations, modeling

I'm trying to create a mathematical model for COVID-19, to help my city, using the follow system of equations:

```
odesSEIQRD = {
Derivative[1][S][t] == (-β)*S[t]*(I[t]/(η - Q[t] - D[t])), 
Derivative[1][E][t] == (-ζ)*E[t] + β*S[t]*(I[t]/(η - Q[t] - D[t])), 
Derivative[1][I][t] == ζ*E[t] - γ*I[t] - μ*I[t] - δ*I[t],
Derivative[1][Q][t] == δ*I[t] - γ*Q[t] - ϵ*Q[t], 
Derivative[1][R][t] == γ*I[t] + γ*Q[t],
Derivative[1][D][t] == μ*I[t] + ϵ*Q[t]
};
sol1=NDSolve[{odesSEIQRD,S[0]==η-I0,E[0]==0,I[0]==I0,Q[0]==0,R[0]==0,D[0]==0},{S,E,I,Q,R,D},{t,0,6000},Method->{"StiffnessSwitching",Method->{"ExplicitRungeKutta",Automatic}}];
```

where

```
η = 212000000;
β = 3.3*λ[t];
ζ = 1/Log[7];
γ = 0.00005;
μ = 0.0063;
ϵ = 0;
δ = 1;
I0 = 76;
```

I need to change Lambda, between 1 and 0, in some specific time (day). Example: lambda = 1 between t=0 and t=5. Lambda = 0.8 between t=5 and t=10, and lambda = 0.4 between t=10 and t=20, Lambda = 0.1 between t=20 and t=30. Finally, I need to plot the curve using this values. It must flatten the I[t] curve. The Lambda parameter is related to social isolation, Lambda = 1 -> no social isolation, Lambda = 0 total social isolation.

Comment: Your code as written produces "Set::wrsym: Symbol N is Protected. >>"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I corrected it.

Comment: (I am not seeing a lambda in those equations, but..) This could be done using `Piecewise`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define any of your "constants" as arbitrary functions of time. In the example you mention, you could use the [`Piecewise` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html#690) to define a discontinuous function of time; or use a `Module` to define a more complex function if need be.